# refresh page, azure or iis reacts with You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

[image: directory structure]I have sucessfully deployed nodejs app in azure. when I navigate to **https://my-app/xyz ** refresh page I see, You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

I tried to edit web-config but still it doesn't work. I am not sure If this is security issue or node.js is not able to serve anything for this route but on my local machine If I do refresh It doesn't show this issue. Thje picture above contains the directory structure and /client has Angular compiled files.Thank you

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I will try this Tony and let you know soon if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Any update on your side about this question?

Comment: I am currently working on it

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error. I suppose you access the website via a virtual directory.

- Make sure you have set the correct virtual directory for your app.
  It should be the virtual path `/xyz`, Physical Path `site\wwwroot\yourcustomfoldername`. It will be something like this,
  [image]
- Make sure the Physical Path match the actual root directory of your web app in KUDU site.
  [image]